# Publish Failed when Native AOT publish enabled in .Net 8 Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022, .net-8.0, native-aot

I have created a console application targeting .NET 8 using Visual Studio 2022. I have checked the Enable native AOT publish option when creating the project. It gives the below error.

[image]

[image]

**Error Text:**

> Publish has encountered an error. Publish has encountered an error. We
> were unable to determine the cause of the error. Check the output log
> for more details.
>
> A diagnostic log has been written to the following location:
> "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp227D.tmp"

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/native-aot/?tabs=net7%2Cwindows#publish-native-aot-using-the-cli) article only talk about CLI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to solve the issue by selecting the Target runtime to win-x64 in Profile Setting, It was Portable by default. We need to provide the specific runtime identifier.

[image]

Comment: Your answer is helpful, you can mark it so that it can help more people

Comment: @wenbingeng-MSFT done, thank you for reminding me